# Dicom: What are my options?

Tags: archive, images

After a cursory Googling, I can't find a legitimate list of DICOM vendors. I've tried DCM4Chee, Conquest, and PacsOne.  Each server seems to have it's own quirks and annoyances, memory leaks, etc...

I'd like to see what people use for their DICOM servers.  Usually [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicom) would have something like this at the bottom of the article, but it doesn't so I'm wondering if the SF community can create a canonical list.

I must admit that whereas I do not represent any DICOM server vendor.  There is a guy in my office who will buy me a huge [burrito](http://www.flickr.com/photos/scuzzi/381402571/) for each DICOM server I successfully install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a lot of information as to what you are looking for, but here is a good resource to start with: 
http://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part8.html

Its a strange question, since there are difference...'levels' of DICOM servers. At the small end, it seems that almost every piece of software that reads DICOMs has some small DICOM server included. The other extreme being a full blown PACS.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info in the question, I'm just a programmer who likes burritos.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using Conquest with a mysql backend on Windows 2003 server in a research environment, and have had zero problems.  Research image data is quite a bit larger than clinical.  I like Conquest because I could modify the data directory structure to our liking.  This was important to us because I share out the root level of the directory as read only so investigators can get their DICOM files if they wish.

If I wanted a full blown, free PACS on a Unix system, I'd go with DCM4CHEE.

If I wanted a full blown, free PACS on a Windows system, I'd go with [Clearcanvas](http://www.clearcanvas.ca).

If you're looking at commercial solutions, we currently use and like AMICAS in our clinical environment.

Comment: I was going to attempt clearcanvas, can't seem to register for it. They've got a non-helpful DotNetNuke registration form going on there that crashes.  Do you know of an alternate download location by chance?

Comment: I would suggest contacting them about it:  http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/ContactUs/tabid/56/Default.aspx.  I set it up once, and I was impressed.  Nice product for the $$.